# Committing container changes of files generated in /workspace (even using makefile) doesn't persist into new instances of the image

Tags: java, bash, docker, antlr, dockerfile

I am using a java program which generates a lot of files (i.e ANTLR to generate parsers using a grammar). When I perform:

```
java -cp "/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.5-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH" org.antlr.v4.Tool Java8.g4 && javac *.java
```

in the interactive shell using a docker image, certain java files and their classes are generated in the current directory.

But when I perform this in the Dockerfile using:

```
RUN java -cp "/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.5-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH" org.antlr.v4.Tool Java8.g4 && javac *.java
```

the files don't seem to be generated.

Any reason why this is happening and how I could perhaps correct this to generate the files using the RUN instruction in the Dockerfile?

**UPDATE 1:**
More info, my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM blah/blah_java
MAINTAINER blabla
RUN apt-get install -y make wget
RUN mkdir -p /usr/java && wget -O java.tar.gz http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u40-b25/jdk-8u40-linux-x64.tar.gz --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" && tar xfz java.tar.gz -C /usr/java
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40
ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
      .
      .
      .
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/lib && cd /usr/local/lib && wget http://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.5-complete.jar
ENV CLASSPATH=".:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.5-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH"
      .
      .
      .
RUN mkdir -p /workspace/antlr-test/
ADD Java8.g4 /workspace/antlr-test/
WORKDIR /workspace/antlr-test/
RUN java -cp "/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.5-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH" org.antlr.v4.Tool Java8.g4 && javac *.java
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Outputs something like this on building:

```
Step 1 : FROM blah/blah_java
 ---> ff083dedeeac
Step 2 : MAINTAINER blabla
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b2cc75d73e93
Step 3 : RUN apt-get install -y make wget
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e8f8162ca496
Step 4 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/java && wget -O java.tar.gz http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u40-b25/jdk-8u40-linux-x64.tar.gz --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" && tar xfz java.tar.gz -C /usr/java
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1587950d483a
Step 5 : ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1787ea5c62c4
Step 6 : ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5f9082023d2c
       .
       .
       .
Step 10 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/lib && cd /usr/local/lib && wget http://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.5-complete.jar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7a67f6c4c572
Step 11 : ENV CLASSPATH ".:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.5-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c64a24b809f0
        .
        .
        .
Step 14 : RUN mkdir -p /workspace/antlr-test/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 27b18aab274f
Step 15 : ADD Java8.g4 /workspace/antlr-test/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 87ace495d90b
Step 16 : WORKDIR /workspace/antlr-test/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 31089935532b
Step 17 : RUN java -cp "/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.5-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH" org.antlr.v4.Tool Java8.g4 && javac *.java
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 773c302ecf5e
Successfully built 773c302ecf5e
```

**UPDATE 3:**
On having 'ls' in the last RUN instruction as:

```
RUN java -cp "/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.5-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH" org.antlr.v4.Tool Java8.g4 && javac *.java && ls -la
```

I find that the files generated are listed correctly. It is in committing the changes that this is not working.

**UPDATE 4:**
I also find that in the interactive shell of the image, the files are generated. But when I commit the changes, they are not visible the next time I run them. On performing a `docker diff , before committing the changes, I find that the files generated are not listen here.

**UPDATE 5:**
Looks like the files generated are not persisted across image builds/commits if they are in one of the subdirectories in /workspace directory. If they are made to generate outside workspace, they seem to persist through builds/commits.

Comment: Show the Dockerfile, or a reproducer, does you Dockerfile have some `WORKDIR` or such commands before?

Comment: I have updated the question and added my dockerfile contents, yes I do have a WORKDIR instruction before the problematic RUN instruction.

Comment: do you have *.java in /workspace/antlr-test/ ?

Comment: Java files are supposed to be generated when `java -cp "/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.5-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH" org.antlr.v4.Tool Java8.g4` is run. This works when I run this in interactive shell but it doesn't seem to generate the Javafiles when I run it from RUN instruction in the Dockerfile (i.e. I don't see the files when I build and run the image through the Dockerfile). I don't get any errors either, the image builds fine.

Comment: During the `docker build`, do you see any message that might explain this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108160/discussion-between-user2915097-and-np20).

Answer (score 0):

Docker keeps old build steps as a optimization (this is part of dockers strength).

If you change a Dockerfile and build, the new image will use cache for everything BEFORE the change and rebuild everything after it.

Restoring the changed line in the Dockerfile will re-activate the cached build.

You can invalidate the cache by flags to docker build or you can add lines to your Dockerfile to remind you when you invalidated everything below that part last. For example adding/editing the following line will invalidate the cache below it.

```
ENV FORCED_DOCKER_REBUILD=2018-01-01
```